# Running an Arduino program in NetBeans 7.3

Tags: arduino, netbeans-plugins

I am using Arduino and [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) in my project. My final work is to switch from Arduino program to [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29). I managed to install an Arduino-NetBeans plugin as described in *[Arduino - NetBeans Plugin detail](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46054/arduino)*

My Arduino program includes

```
Serial.begin(9600); /////// Serial.print();
```

I get an error saying that "Unable to resolve identifier Serial". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

this is what you have to add to your source file:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
// imports the Serial class to allow log output
extern HardwareSerial Serial;
```

then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

As answered by cgo you can add `extern HardwareSerial Serial;`

[image: netbeans arduino serial]

Or into your Project Settings, go to BUILD > C++ COMPILER > PREPROCESSOR DEFINITIONS and add: `__AVR_ATmega328P__` (if you are working with Arduino UNO)

[image: netbeans arduino preprocessor]

Answer (score 0):

The message "unable to resolve identifier Serial" means that the compiler is searching for the variable `Serial`, but cannot find its declaration. You should check if you include all header files properly. I don't know the NetBeans plugin, but I guess the Serial-structure/class is initialised there.

If that is not helping, you should check the compiler otions and set them to default, as described on the project-site.